# how to best handle system.reflection.propertyInfo NULLReferenceExceptions

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, system.reflection

```
  public DataTable GenericListToDataTable(object list)
    {
        DataTable dt = null;
        Type listType = list.GetType();
        if (listType.IsGenericType)
        {
          Type elementType = listType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
             dt = new DataTable(elementType.Name + "List");


            MemberInfo[] miarray = elementType.GetMembers(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            foreach (MemberInfo mi in miarray)
            {
                if (mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
                {
                    PropertyInfo pi = mi as PropertyInfo;
                    dt.Columns.Add(pi.Name, pi.PropertyType);

                }
                else if (mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)
                {
                    FieldInfo fi = mi as FieldInfo;
                    dt.Columns.Add(fi.Name, fi.FieldType);
                }
            }

            //populate the table 
            IList il = list as IList;
            foreach (object record in il)
            {
                int i = 0;
                object[] fieldValues = new object[dt.Columns.Count];
                foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
                {
                    MemberInfo mi = elementType.GetMember(c.ColumnName)[0];
                    if (mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
                    {
                        PropertyInfo pi = mi as PropertyInfo;
                        fieldValues[i] = pi.GetValue(record, null);
                    }
                    else if (mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)
                    {
                        FieldInfo fi = mi as FieldInfo;
                        fieldValues[i] = fi.GetValue(record);
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(fieldValues);
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

In the above code, i am trying to convert a generic List to a DataTable but i am having trouble on how best to handle NullRefrenceException at                         `dt.Columns.Add(pi.Name, pi.PropertyType);` and

```
dt.Columns.Add(fi.Name, fi.FieldType);
```

I have tried

```
if (pi != null) dt.Columns.Add(pi.Name, pi.PropertyType);
```

but still get the following below

***System.NotSupportedException: DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>.***

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: of course you need to skip null values as you have done!

The answer might not be what you want to hear: DataColumn simply does not support Nullable types. Check the code:

```
    // System.Data.DataColumn
    public DataColumn(string columnName, Type dataType, string expr, MappingType type)
    {
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        Bid.Trace("<ds.DataColumn.DataColumn|API> %d#, columnName='%ls', expr='%ls', type=%d{ds.MappingType}\n", this.ObjectID, columnName, expr, (int)type);
        if (dataType == null)
        {
            throw ExceptionBuilder.ArgumentNull("dataType");
        }
        StorageType storageType = DataStorage.GetStorageType(dataType);
        if (DataStorage.ImplementsINullableValue(storageType, dataType))
        {
            throw ExceptionBuilder.ColumnTypeNotSupported();
        }
        this._columnName = ((columnName == null) ? "" : columnName);
        SimpleType simpleType = SimpleType.CreateSimpleType(dataType);
        if (simpleType != null)
        {
            this.SimpleType = simpleType;
        }
        this.UpdateColumnType(dataType, storageType);
        if (expr != null && 0 < expr.Length)
        {
            this.Expression = expr;
        }
        this.columnMapping = type;
    }
```

where `ImplementsNullableValue` looks like this:

```
    // System.Data.Common.DataStorage
    internal static bool ImplementsINullableValue(StorageType typeCode, Type dataType)
    {
        return typeCode == StorageType.Empty && dataType.IsGenericType && dataType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>);
    }
```

So I am afraid you are down to 2 possibilites:

- Either skip Nullable types
- Create a wrapper class for your nullable types (depends if this is doable, e.g. lots of bool? will be quite some work)